GRUB не "видит" файл grub.cfg
Расклад такой. Debian 12. Vmware. Два сервера – dhcp и tftp+apache2. Пытаюсь с третьего клиент-сервера загрузить Debian UEFI по PXE через grub. IP выдается верный, NBP загружается, то есть grub. Это все, grub.cfg не загружается, vmlinuz и initrd тоже. Меню выбора нет. "Голый" grub на экране и все на этом.
Что делать?
Пытался менять /etc/dhcp/ dhcpd.conf,  /srv/tftp/ grub.cfg. Думал использовать pxelinux.0, но по какой-то причине этого загрузчика нет в syslinux (переустановка, загрузка на чистую ОС не помогают). Покидал grub.cfg во все возможные директории, но все равно не видит.
Скрины: https://imgur.com/a/WoArEYp
Буду признателен за помощь ☺
